# Could not access files from FTP Server using Azure datafactory

Tags: azure-data-factory, ftp-server

I am trying to copy files from FTPServer to Azure Blob store.I have reffered below link :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-ftp-connector

The FTPLinked Service gets deployed but when I execute the pipeline, the output dataset fails giving below error:

[image]

Even after trying with wizard "Copy Data(preview)" from Azure portal, I am not able to connect to FTPServer.

[image]

I am able to connect FTPServer via FileZilla. But when I am trying to access file from Azure Datafactory then it fails.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you really using port 990 and not 21?